# What is the recommended way to store secret tokens in a react native app?

Tags: react-native, redux

What is the most secure and the recommended way to store things like access tokens in a react native app? Shall I store them in the android shared preferences, in the redux store or AsyncStorage?

Comment: What kind of access tokens? You should _not_ publish an app containing _your_ access token to a third-party API, for example.

Comment: @CodeCaster Like access tokens which we get after authorizing with the API.

Comment: Which API do you mean?

Comment: An API we built to connect the main web app with the mobile app

Comment: So why do you want to store those "securely"? Who should not be allowed to access those tokens?